# How to encode escape characters for url?

Tags: java, spring, url, encoding, sitemap

I need to add some url's to sitemap.
As stated in [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533465/should-i-encode-special-character-in-my-sitemaps) special characters should be escaped.
The problem is

```
http://somesite.com/search/some_mark/model////'''...\\\,,,!!!"""№№№;;;%%%:::???***((()))___++
```

So I have param `///'''...\\\,,,!!!"""№№№;;;%%%:::???***((()))___++` for `model`.

I've tried to do escaping using [spring uri utils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html) `encode` method, this is its output:

```
http://somesite.com/search/some_mark/model/%2F%2F%2F%27%27%27...%5C%5C%5C%2C%2C%2C%21%21%21%22%22%22%E2%84%96%E2%84%96%E2%84%96%3B%3B%3B%25%25%25%3A%3A%3A%3F%3F%3F%2A%2A%2A%28%28%28%29%29%29___%2B%2B
```

As I understand this is legal url, but when I enter it to browser bar I'm getting response code `400 Bad Request`.

I've also tried to encode using java's [URLEncoder.encode(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) method, below its output:

```
http://somesite.com/search/some_mark/model/%2F%2F%2F%27%27%27...%5C%5C%5C%2C%2C%2C%21%21%21%22%22%22%E2%84%96%E2%84%96%E2%84%96%3B%3B%3B%25%25%25%3A%3A%3A%3F%3F%3F***%28%28%28%29%29%29___%2B%2B
```

As you see it's not escaping asterisks (`***`).

So I'm really confused by now. Does spring encode the right way and the output of his method should be considered as legal url ? If yes, then why browser fails to make a request ? If no, what utility should be used for this purposes ?

Comment: Just to be sure, are those two `+` at the end of the url correct. I'm assuming this is some sort of a test, but all the other characters are repeated exactly 3 times and this one just twice, so could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used [Spring URI Utils encode()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method and add explicit check for slashes (both `/` and `\`), so the part after the `/model/` would not contain them.

Basically slashes are reserved special characters that split the url into parts and even if they will be encoded a lot of software operates with them in a special way.

For example if you use nginx in front of your app it might return `Http 400` status code unless you made additional configuration.

If you use tomcat it is also has an option to use encoded slashes in url:

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

Or if your app build on Spring MVC framework it also [might have a problem](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11101) with them.

Basically it needs a lot of configuration.

So my advice would be to think before allowing use of this special characters as a part of url.